# nodejs check url is exist but don't download it

Tags: node.js, curl

nodejs check url is exist but don't download it

I found the npm packages `urlExists` `http`, they make a request and response with the `body data`.

like the command `curl -i url`

I want don't download the `body data` and know the url is exist.

Comment: effectively you cant know if a url exists untill you make a valid request and get the response, at l;east the headers. So there is no other way

Comment: @NikosM.   is exist a way that only request the header info?

Comment: That library makes a HEAD request (as opposed to a GET) which is probably the most minimalistic way to check if a URL responds or not. I cannot see it downloading any body data.

Comment: ok, I understand. thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `HEAD` HTTP method:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response.

[RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

For example:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const response = await fetch('https://google.com', {
    method: 'HEAD'
});

console.log(response.ok);
```

Of course this would rely on the web server properly implementing the RFC.